# How to auto-reload files in Node.js while using ESM?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I understand you can clear files from cache while using CommonJS simply by `delete`ing from `require.cache` and `require`ing the file again. However I've been unable to find an equivalent option when using ESM. Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading at [esm issues](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/307#issuecomment-480353529) it seems cache is intentionally not exposed.

I'm afraid the answer to your question is simply *no*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a **hack** using dynamic imports:

```js
const modules = {
  moduleA: async () => await import(`./module-a.js?v=${Date.now()}`)
}
```

Then use it like:

```js
async function myTest() {
    // module will be reset at each call of the function
    const moduleA = await modules.moduleA() 
}
```

Unfortunately, like said by @lisonge, the memory of the older module will not be freed up, so keep in mind that it can lead to a memory leak in case of intensive usage.

Here is an issue about it with further details on that technique [there](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2751)

Comment: The old version modules that were loaded before were unable to remove from memory. Your solution has made the memory occupy more and more under extreme circumstances

Comment: Thanks @lisonge for pointing this out, I updated my answer to reflect that 